# Magento 2 Custom CSS and JS on CMS page

Tags: magento-2.1, css, cms

I need to add a CSS/JS and HTML to CMS page is that even possible? I wrote a "Calculator" offline, styled it and now facing a problem. How can I add the JS/jQuery and CSS to a CMS page so I can keep my format? I'm using Magento 2.1.8

Answer (score 0):

**For CSS:**

```
<style xml="space"><!--
.class-name{
    your style goes here
}
--></style>
```

**For JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
require([ "jquery" ], function( $ ) {
 alert('working...');
});
// ]]></script>
```

I hope this is useful. Thanks. Thumps up!